# Sorting external json file and pass it into InfoWindow for google map

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps

I am trying to accomplish something like this with Google Map API:

http://www.alphamediausa.com/our-stations/

So each marker will have a bunch of URLs related to that location. I have an external JSON file that I parse and it looks like this:

```
{
  "Market Counts" : "",
  "Market" : "North Dallas",
  "Call Letters" : "KLAK-FM",
  "Location" : "33.2156628,-96.7235993",
  "Website" : "http://www.975klak.com",
},
{
  "Market Counts" : "1",
  "Market" : "North Dallas",
  "Call Letters" : "KMKT-FM",
  "Location" : "33.619403,-96.77182",
  "Website" : "http://www.931kmkt.com",
 },
{
  "Market Counts" : "",
  "Market" : "North Dallas",
  "Call Letters" : "KMAD-FM",
  "Location" : "33.619403,-96.77182",,
  "Website" : "http://www.madrock1025.com",
 },
{
  "Market Counts" : "",
  "Market" : "Palm Springs",
  "Call Letters" : "KKUU-FM",
  "Location" : "33.771553,-116.7043751",
  "Website" : "http://www.u927.com",    
},
{
  "Market Counts" : "",
  "Market" : "Palm Springs",
  "Call Letters" : "KDGL-FM",    
  "Location" : "33.771553,-116.7043751",
  "Website" : "http://www.theeagle1069.com",
},
{
  "Market Counts" : "",
  "Market" : "Palm Springs",
  "Call Letters" : "KDES-FM",
  "Location" : "33.771553,-116.7043751",
  "Website" : "http://www.985thebull.com",
 }
```

There are 263 different JSON object like this. It has Market, Call Letters(stations), Location and Website.

I want to categorize this Call Letters(stations) similar to how 
http://www.alphamediausa.com/our-stations/ does. So I looped the JSON based on "Market" value to store all the Call Letters(stations) based on that "Market Value". I have been searching if there is any solution for that but I couldn't find it. This is what i have done so far:

```
function initMap()
{
    //Reading the json file
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", "../../station-database.json", false);
    request.send(null)
    //creating the json object
    var my_JSON_object = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    //Setting up the map for USA
    var uluru = {
        lat: 37.090240,
        lng: -95.712891
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 5,
        center: uluru,                 
    });

    var num_markers = my_JSON_object.length;

    var temp_arr = [];
    //getting the copy of my obj
    temp_arr = my_JSON_object.slice();

    var lat_lang = [];
    var hovertitle = [];
    var markers = [];
    //Looping json object for markers
    for (var i = 0; i < num_markers; i++)
    {
        var htmlAll = '';
        lat_lang = my_JSON_object[i].Location.split(',');
        hovertitle[i] = my_JSON_object[i].Market + ',' + my_JSON_object[i].State;

        var websites = [];
        var stations = [];
        var market = my_JSON_object[i];

        //looping to categorize Markets and push all relative
        // data into the arrays that will hold the url and Call Letters 
        for(var j=0; j < temp_arr.length; j++)
        {
            //if markets are matching push into array and discard that array key   
            if( market.Market ==  temp_arr[j].Market)
            {
                websites.push(temp_arr[j].Website);
                stations.push(temp_arr[j]['Call Letters']);
                temp_arr.splice(j,1);
            }
        }
        //Store html content that needs to be displayed in the InfoWindow


       for(var site=0; site < websites.length; site++){
            htmlAll =+ '<div><a href="'+websites[site]+' target="_blank">'+stations[site]+'</a></div>';
        }
        //Looping latitude and langtitude
        myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(lat_lang[0]), parseFloat(lat_lang[1]));

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            content: htmlAll,
            title: hovertitle[i]
        }));

        google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function(i) {
            return function() {
                infowindow.setContent(this.title + this.content);
                infowindow.open(map, this);
            }
        }(i));
    }
}
```

I am able to display markers and title properly for each location but I am not able to display the content in InfoWindow. When I do console.log(htmlAll) after this:

```
for(var site=0; site < websites.length; site++){
    htmlAll =+ '<div><a href="'+websites[site]+' target="_blank">'+stations[site]+'</a></div>';
}
```

I can see some of to relative results but nothing shows up in InfoWindow. I am not sure if I am making a logical mistake with IF statement that check Market or with categorizing Market or with FOR loops?

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be coming from your `addListener` implementation.

First of all, why are you returning a function in the listener's callback?
You should directly do the `infowindow.setContent(this.title + this.content);` and `infowindow.open(map, this);` statements in the `function (i) {...}` instead of returning a function.

In addition to that, I will change the following lines of code:

```js
markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    content: htmlAll,
    title: hovertitle[i]
}));

google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function(i) {
    return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(this.title + this.content);
        infowindow.open(map, this);
    }
}(i));
```

By the following:

```js
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    content: htmlAll,
    title: hovertitle[i]
});
markers.push(marker);

marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(this.title + this.content);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
});
```

As described in the Google Maps documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried it, I am able to see the title but somehow I still don't see the content in InfoWindow. When I console.log(htmlAll) before the marker is declared, I can see all the content in htmlAll.

Comment: Can you do `console.log(this.content);` in the click listener, just before doing the `setContent`on the infowindow? What do you have? Also, I suggest you declare only 1 infowindow object instead of having one declared infowindow per marker.